# Client Communication is currently not established for Acrobat OpenDoc.edt

Tags: latex, acrobat, pdflatex

My MiKTex is running on WinEdit 5.5, and my Acrobat is X pro 2010. I can run PdfLatex and I can see the PDF file in WinEdit. But shortly after I open the Pdf file, the  Acrobat OpenDoc.edt file pops up with the error message as the picture:

[image]

Comment: Hi Nimantha, thank you very much for your help. I  think you're right:  My MiKTex is installed in a local 32 bit while others are in 64bit. I wonder How I can fix the problem?

Comment: @KJ: Hey Pai, to clarify, I had edited the question, however, the comment was by KJ; for future reference, to notify a specific user when posting a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), mention them using @ followed by their name (which will be prompted in a format without spaces) - for example in this comment, I had sent a notification to K J